# Connect with filezilla to docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, filezilla, docker-container

I am running docker containers on Google Cloud virtual machine. I am trying for hours to connect from filezilla on my local computer to an running docker container. I have started docker image like this:

```
docker run -t -d --name test -p 2222:22 --link postgres7:postgres7 random_image /bin/bash
```

In my filezilla connection configuration I have set:
Host: Google Cloud IP address
Port: 2222
Protocol: SFTP
Logon Type: Normal
User: root (without password)

When trying to connect I get this error:

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:2222...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@x.x.x.x" 2222
Error:  Connection refused
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have opened ports on google cloud engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is not recommended to install ssh server on docker containers but here is how I did it:

1. Install ssh client

`apt-get install openssh-server`

2. Set password on root (or any user you want to connect with)

`passwd (enter password twice)`

3. In /etc/ssh/sshd_config change:

`PermitRootLogin without-password`

to

`PermitRootLogin yes`

4. Restart ssh server

`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

And now you will be able to connect with any ftp client as root to your docker container with password that you set.

Comment: its a centos 7 docker image from fauria/docker-vsftpd, after doing all this it says no such file /etc/init.d/ssh, also systemctl restart sshd and service sshd restart also not working

if you have tried at your hand?

Comment: @aniruddha I have only tried this on ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and it is working for me. I am not sure for CentOS. Did you try /etc/init.d/ssh restart. Also, maybe it would be neccessary to add --privileged option to docker run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then search with Ctrl + W for `PasswordAuth` and modify it to yes.

Then you can try login in via `sftp://` to your IP through Port 22.